# shell scripting: how to cut line in variable

Tags: shell, awk, cut

I'm new to shell scripting. I've tried to search online, but I couldn't find what I was looking for - how do I cut a variable to get the value I'm looking for?

for example I have:

```
Result=`awk -F : -v "Title=" -v "Author=" 'tolower() == tolower(Title) && tolower() == tolower(Author)' BookDB.txt`
//which will return:
//Result= Black:Hat:12.30:20:30
```

I've tried doing this, but it won't work:

```
PRICE= cut -d ":" -f 3 $Result
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not wrong ... well, at least most of it!

Doing `echo 'Result= Black:Hat:12.30:20:30' | cut -d ":" -f 3` will give the result `12.30`.

The issue is that you probably want to use it on a shell script.
To do that just try the following:
`` PRICE=`cut -d ":" -f 3 $Result` ``

What I did was basically putting `` ` `` before and after the expression that you want to store in your variable.

Reference to learn more: http://www.freeos.com/guides/lsst/ch02sec08.html

Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

How about using awk...

```
input="Black:Hat:12.30:20:30"
first=$(echo input | awk -F":" '{print $1}')
echo $first
second=$(echo $input | awk -F":" '{print $2}')
echo $second
date=$(echo $input | awk -F":" '{print $3 ":" $4 ":" $5}')
echo $date
```

You might have to edit to fit your exact requirements.

Comment: Avoid using old and outdated back-tiks, use parentheses: `second=$(echo $input | awk -F":" '{print $2}')`